# What factors influence the memorization in a young adult?

Tags: mental-health, brain, memory

I am a currently a 23 year-old pre-med student and I am worried because I tend to forget things easily.

*To give you some examples: in class, I miss out on a lot of the information and in my every day life, I can't remember names of movies, actors. Things "slip out" of my mind a lot.*

I have realised that distraction makes it even worse.

Interestingly, if something is logical, it will stick in my brain, but if its pure memorization, I most likely won't remember it.

**I would like to know which factors influence the memorization in a young adult?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Memorization is a skill, and like all skills it can be learned. Find a book on memorization techniques and read it. This isn't a health question.

Comment: is this new? memory loss may be a symptom (eg of sleep deprivation or overdrinking, two common things in students.) If it's not new, it's off topic here, Personal Productivity might ne helpful though.

Comment: @KateGregory And if it is new, it's still off topic because it's a request for personal medical advice.

Comment: @Carey Gregory. I have tried to edit the question (by taking into account the suggestion made by JJosaur) to make it look more general. What do you think? Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith.

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith Yes, much better.

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith The question may make more sense now, but it is not what I was asking. My concern isn't just memorizing stuff. Forgetting to do things is my main concern, which isn't a skill that can be learned overtime. Anyways, I think this wasn't the right platform to ask.

Comment: @JagmeetSingh. Thanks. Well, I had to heavily edit your question (which was voted to close several times btw) as it was asking for personal medical advice which is off topic here (and the format wasn't great neither). Though, I am not sure I understand what you mean by _"My concern isn't just memorizing stuff. Forgetting to do things is my main concern"_. Isn't forgetting relied to problems in memorization? If you can't encode, store or retrieve information, doesn't this lead to forgetting them? Hope you could still find some help in my answer. Good luck. Best regards, M.Arrowsmith

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith The links you provided definitely look helpful. I will read through them. When I say "forgetting things" I mean, for example, if someone told me to do something in 20 minutes, it would slip out of my mind. Then I would get a call from that person, and then I would feel "oh shoot, how did I forget?". This occurs too often. There is no memorization involved I believe. Another example, if I am supposed to take a freeway, I would get distracted with some thoughts and just forget to take it. I don't see how one memorizes to do that stuff. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith and another confusion in the "question" was that I didn't ask a question. I just described my situation. I guess what I really wanted to know was that is this a medical condition? Or does this happen to a lot of people? I certainly believe that it doesn't, but just wanted to ask. Not seeking a medical advice. :)

Comment: @JagmeetSingh. I am not sure what you understand by _I didn't ask a question_? Before my edit of your question, you asked _Why do I forget easily_, isn't this a question? Also, I am confused by your statement "_I guess what I really wanted to know was that is this a medical condition_ " but you then add "_Not seeking a medical advice_". Tbh, I don't really see the difference. And finally, if you find the time to read my answer carefully as well as the links provided, you would realise that there are a lot of factors possibly affecting memory and you are certainly not an isolated case. BR

Comment: @JagmeetSingh. _if someone told me to do something in 20 minutes, it would slip out of my mind_, _There is no memorization involved I believe_. If this has nothing to do with *memorization*, could you explain me what it is and the neurobiological pathways involved then? From my knowledge/experience, this is linked to memorization. Similar with your sentence _I would get distracted with some thoughts and just forget to take it_. Tbh I think you should have a look at a Neuroscience book (e.g Kandel Principles of Neuroscience) and have some lecture on the pathways involved in memorization. BR

Answer (score 10):

Memory is a complex cognitive function which relies on several neuronal pathways. Without wanting to go into too much details, **the process of memorization is dependent on three different steps: encoding, storage and retrieval.**

Different brain regions are involved in the process of memorisation: hippocampus and mamillary bodies are the main brain regions (which get also affected in Alzheimer's Disease or Korsakof Disease) but other regions have been reported to be involved in the process such as the striatum or the amygdala.

As complex as it is, the different steps of memorization can be influenced by diseases but also by different other "factors" such as (non exhaustive list):

- Emotions/Motivation/Mood: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16371950, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2656292/
- Sleep (eg sleep deprivation): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23589831
- Attention: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9460740
- Drugs (eg cannabis): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19630708
- Caffeine consumption: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3222359
- Diet: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2805706/

***So to summarise: difficulty in memorization can be multifactorial. You might wish considering one of those above mentionned factors and try to work on them.***

P.S: you tagged your question with "dementia". I have already answered a similar question for someone aged 30-40, you might have a look here: [Dementia in late 30s, early 40s? Tests?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/dementia-in-late-30s-early-40s-tests/7286)